# polylines are not getting cleared in flutter map

Tags: websocket, geolocation, polyline, fluttermap, polylineoptions

When the user is outside of the building the polyline should disappear. But polyline still visible even if the user is outside of the building:

```
`map_view.dart`
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../view_model/map_view_model.dart';
class MapViewWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapViewWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MapViewWidget> createState() => _MapViewWidgetState();
}

class _MapViewWidgetState extends State<MapViewWidget>{
  late MapViewModel viewModel;



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    viewModel = Provider.of<MapViewModel>(context, listen: false);
    print("viewModel.position:::::${viewModel.getCurrentLocation()}");
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      viewModel.getCurrentLocation();
      viewModel.initializeCompass();
      viewModel.initializeMapController();
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Consumer<MapViewModel>(
     builder: (context, viewModel, _){
    return viewModel.position!= null ? Stack(
      children: [
        FlutterMap(
          mapController: viewModel.mapController,
          options: MapOptions(
            zoom: 10.0,
            // center: LatLng(17.441990,78.381939),
            center: LatLng(viewModel.position!.latitude, viewModel.position!.longitude),
            maxZoom: 20.0,
            onPositionChanged: viewModel.handlePositionChanged,
            interactiveFlags: ~InteractiveFlag.rotate,
          ),
          layers: viewModel.mapLayers,
        ),
        StreamBuilder(
          stream: viewModel.channel.stream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              viewModel.polylineCoordinates.clear();
              Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(snapshot.data);
              List<dynamic> coordinates = data['coordinates'][0];
              for (var coordinate in coordinates) {
                double longitude = coordinate[0];
                double latitude = coordinate[1];
                viewModel.polylineCoordinates.add(LatLng(latitude, longitude));
              }
              print("polylineCoordinates::${viewModel.polylineCoordinates.length}");
              return const Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Text('data Received',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,decoration: TextDecoration.none,fontSize: 10.0),)
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Text('Error');
            } else {
              viewModel.polylineCoordinates.clear();
              return const Text('');
              // return Text('Waiting for messages...');
            }
          },
        ),
      ],
    ) : Dialog(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[100],
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child:  Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: const [
            CircularProgressIndicator(),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Center(child: Text("Please wait..Map is Loading")),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
     }
     );
  }
}
`map_view_model.dart`

import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_compass/flutter_compass.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';
import 'package:maps_soumya/loading_view_model.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';

import '../../map_util.dart';
import '../../rotation_marker.dart';

class MapViewModel extends LoadingViewModel {

  final channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://aims.vassarlabs.com/webSocket');

  Position? position;
  late MapController mapController;

  //Map Layers
  List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates=[];
  List<Marker> mapMarkers = [];
  List<CircleMarker> circles = [];
  List<Polygon> polygons = [];
  final List<Polyline> polylines = [];
  List<LayerOptions> mapLayers = [];

  double lat = -1;
  double lng = -1;
  double compassHeading = 0.0;
  double circleRadius = 50.0;
  double rotation = 0.0;
  double accuracy = 0.0;

  initializeMapController() {
    mapController = MapController();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // getCurrentLocation() async{
  //   await Geolocator.checkPermission();
  //   await Geolocator.requestPermission();
  //   position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
  //   notifyListeners();
  //   rotation = position.heading;
  //
  //   createMapLayers();
  // }
  getCurrentLocation() async {
    mapController=MapController();
    LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    }
    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      // Handle denied permission case
      return;
    }
    position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
    );
    print("position:::$position");
    lat = position!.latitude;
    print("position.latitude and position.longitude${position!.latitude} ${position!.longitude}");
    lng = position!.longitude;
    await getUserPositionStream();
    rotation = position!.heading;
    notifyListeners();
    createMapLayers();
  }

  getUserPositionStream() async {
    var locationOptions=const LocationSettings(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high, distanceFilter: 0);
    Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: locationOptions).listen((Position position) {
      if(this.position != position) {
          this.position = position;
          accuracy=position.accuracy;
          _updateMarker();
          createMapLayers();
          notifyListeners();
          // getCurrentLocation();
      }
    });
    // double lat = 17.441990;
    // double lon = 78.381939;
    //westin::::cordinates(17.44257,78.38165)
    // double lat=17.44257;
    // double lon=78.38165;

    double lat = position!.latitude;
    double lon=  position!.longitude;

    String latLonString = '$lon,$lat';
    print("latLonString:::$latLonString");
    print("lat:::$lat");
    print("lon:::$lon");

    // channel.sink.add(latLonString);

    bool isInPolylines = MapUtil.containsLocation(LatLng(lat, lon), polylineCoordinates, false);
    if (!isInPolylines) {
      polylineCoordinates.clear();
      polylines.clear();
      _buildPolylines(polylineCoordinates);
      getCurrentLocation();
      channel.sink.add(latLonString);
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }


  List<Polyline> _buildPolylines(List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates) {
    Polyline polyline = Polyline(
      points: polylineCoordinates,
      color: Colors.yellow, // Customize the color of the polyline
      strokeWidth: 2, // Customize the width of the polyline
    );
    polylines.add(polyline);
    return polylines;
  }

  void handlePositionChanged(MapPosition position, bool hasGesture) {
    if (hasGesture) {
      final zoomLevel = position.zoom;
      final newRadius = calculateCircleRadius(zoomLevel!);
      circleRadius = newRadius;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  double calculateCircleRadius(double zoomLevel) {
    return 50.0 * pow(2, 13 - zoomLevel);
  }

  initializeCompass() {
    FlutterCompass.events!.listen((event) {
      compassHeading = event.heading ?? 0.0;
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  createMapLayers() {
    mapLayers.clear();
    mapLayers.addAll([
      TileLayerOptions(
          urlTemplate: 'http://mt3.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',
          subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
          maxZoom: 20
      ),
      MarkerLayerOptions(
          markers: [
            Marker(
                point: LatLng(position!.latitude, position!.longitude),
                // point: LatLng(17.441990,78.381939),
                builder: (context)=> RotationMarker(
                  rotation: compassHeading,
                  builder: (context)=> Stack(
                    children: [
                      const Icon(Icons.tornado_sharp,size: 30,color: Colors.lightBlue,),
                      Positioned(
                        top:10,left: 4.1,bottom:0,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          "assets/images/current_location_gif.gif",
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  size: 50.0,
                )
            ),

          ]
      ),
      PolygonLayerOptions(
        polygons: [
          Polygon(
            points: _createCirclePoints(LatLng(position!.latitude, position!.longitude), 0.001), // Adjust the radius as per your preference
            color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.2),
            borderColor: Colors.transparent,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      PolylineLayerOptions(
          polylines: polylines
      ),
      ]
    );
  }


  List<LatLng> _createCirclePoints(LatLng center, double radius) {
    const int numberOfPoints = 100;
    final List<LatLng> points = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++) {
      final double angle = 2 * pi * i / numberOfPoints;
      final double x = center.latitude + radius * cos(angle);
      final double y = center.longitude + radius * sin(angle);
      points.add(LatLng(x, y));
    }
    return points;
  }

  void _updateMarker() {
    mapMarkers.clear();
    circles.clear();
    if (position != null) {
      mapMarkers.add(
        Marker(
          point: LatLng(position!.latitude, position!.longitude),
          // point: LatLng(17.441990,78.381939),
          // point: LatLng(17.44257,78.38165),
          builder: (context)=>RotationMarker(
            rotation: position!.heading,
            builder: (context)=> Stack(
              children: [
                const Icon(Icons.tornado_sharp,size: 30,color: Colors.lightBlue,),
                Positioned(
                  top:10,left: 4.1,bottom:0,
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "assets/images/current_location_gif.gif",
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            color: Colors.blue,
            size: 50.0,
          ),
        ),
      );
      circles.add(
          CircleMarker(
            point: LatLng(position!.latitude, position!.longitude),
            radius: circleRadius,
            color: Colors.lightBlue.shade50.withOpacity(0.2),
            borderColor: Colors.red,
            borderStrokeWidth: 2,)
      );
      notifyListeners();
    }
    // mapMarkers.add();
  }
}
```

[image: example image]

What to happen: If the user is outside of the building the polyline should disappear. and if the user enters another building the building should highlight with polyline. And polyline coordinates are obtained from a WebSocket stream that receives data from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today(polygons not updating correctly) on `flutter: 3.10.6`. Updating to latest stable `flutter: 3.13.7` fixed the issue for me.